# Android, How to invert Google ml Kit ImageProxy colors?

Tags: android, google-mlkit

I'm developing an Android Application.
I am trading with Google ML Kit. But I need to invert the colors when rendering with Imageproxy.
I am able to invert the image with OpenCV. But I can't convert it to Imageproxy. How can I invert image colors?

i need your help

```
InputImage image = InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees());
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = ImageConvertUtils.getInstance().getUpRightBitmap(image);
                    Mat tmp = new Mat (bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
                    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, tmp);
                    Core.bitwise_not(tmp, tmp);
                    Utils.matToBitmap(tmp, bitmap);
}  catch (MlKitException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to run inverted image with ML Kit. You don't need to convert it back to ImageProxy, just create another InputImage and feed it to ML Kit

```
InputImage invertedImage = InputImage.fromBitmap(yourBitmap, 0);
```

Comment: Perfect answer. I fed it with InputImage. However, I was not able to do `imageProxy.close()` with InputImage. Can you help me?

`requestDetectInImage(imageProxy,graphicOverlay,null,true)
                .addOnCompleteListener(results ->imageProxy.close());`

What should I write in the question mark?

`requestDetectInImage(InputImage,graphicOverlay,null,true)
                .addOnCompleteListener(?????????);`

Comment: In `addOnCompleteListener ` you just need to close the original ImageProxy. The new `Bitmap` versioned `InputImage` doesn't need extra memory management work(You can still recycle the Bitmap if you want, however that is not necessary right now)